# Double integral Clarification

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the double integral.
$$\iint  (x^2 − xy) dA$$

$R$ is the region enclosed by $y=x$ and $y=3x-x^2$

A little lost. My approach $x=0, x=3 y=x, y=3x-x^2$, $\iint(x^2-xy) dydx$.

I end up with $\frac{81}{20}$ but I am not sure of my values taken up for $x$ are correct. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parabola and the line intersect at the origin and at $(2,2)$.  You can see this by solving $y = x = 3x - x^2$.

So you integrate over $x$ from $0$ to $2$, and over $y$ from $x$ to $3x-x^2$:

$$\int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=x}^{3x-x^2}(x^2-xy) dx dy.$$

Can you take it from here?